# How move a view along subview if UIgestureRecogniser added on MainView?

Tags: ios, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, subviews

I have a view on that added a `UITextView`. I have added a `UIgestureRecognizer` on main view if i move the main view it's move with `UItextView` but if I moved from UItextView view then main view is not moving along that.

Tried:- By doing `UITextView` `userInteractionEnabled` disable then it's work but I should make it active when there is no drag.

Answer (score 0):

Used `PanGestureReconizer` and handle

```
-(void)handleResizePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)p {

if (p.state ==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    touchStart = [p translationInView:self];
    touchStart = CGPointMake(touchStart.x - self.bounds.size.width,
                             touchStart.y - self.bounds.size.height);

}
if (p.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {


        touchPoint = [p translationInView:self];
        self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y,
                                touchPoint.x - touchStart.x, touchPoint.y - touchStart.y);
        UITextView *textV = (UITextView*)[self viewWithTag:100];
        textV.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x+HotCornerHeight/2, self.bounds.origin.y+HotCornerHeight/2,
                                 touchPoint.x - touchStart.x-HotCornerHeight, touchPoint.y - touchStart.y-HotCornerHeight);

        UIButton *resButton = (UIButton*)[self viewWithTag:102];
        resButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width-resizeButton,self.bounds.size.height-resizeButton, resizeButton,resizeButton);

}

if (p.state ==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || p.state ==UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    return;
}
}
```

'

Hope this will save some time in future for others.